# Python отредактировать exe файл и сохранить под новым именем

Tags: python

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
filename = '111.exe'
with open(filename, 'rb') as fin:
    sourcedata = fin.read()
    print(sourcedata)
    
new_data = sourcedata.replace('Tllx', 'XzqedTllx')
with open ('222.exe', 'w') as f:
  f.write(new_data)
```

Мне на строку `new_data = sourcedata.replace('Tllx', 'XzqedTllx')` выдает такую ошибку `a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Что делать?

Comment: Замените `'Tllx'` на `b'Tllx'`, `'XzqedTllx'` на `b'XzqedTllx'` и `'w'` на `'wb'`

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало!)